# How to get locale using Php

Tags: php

How to get Locale using Php,I want to get the time zone based on the location,
is there any possibility to get in php.

I need to convert it to GMT and save Database.Again i need to Pull it back to UI with same time same time zone.

Comment: The locale of the machine PHP is running on or the locale of the user making the HTTP request that is being processes by PHP?

Comment: `locale` != `location` I beleive you mean `location`, `locale` is a setting for country and language of a system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the client's locale or timezone from the server side, and you can only make a guess at it from the client side, using JavaScript.

(You can get more locale information if the browser supports Java, but that's a bit of a pain and everyone hates applets.)

To handle timezones in a web application, store all your times as UTC timestamps, and convert them to text for on-page formatting using a user-chosen timezone. You can use methods [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853474/can-i-get-the-browser-time-zone-in-asp-net-or-do-i-have-to-rely-on-js-operations) to guess at the timezone, but since this is not reliable you should also allow the user to explicitly choose timezone.

Comment: we are working on php website that allow the user to configure the schdule time of the message(SMS).so we need allow the end user set time in various zone.

Comment: Yes... the user will have to specify the `timezone_identifier` they are using manually, to pass to `date_default_timezone_set` as described by Sarfraz. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php for the list of identifiers; you could put them in a drop-down box or other UI. You can use JavaScript to pick a best-guess timezone for the default value of the drop-down, as in the question I linked, or simply default to UTC. Once the user has input a time and timezone, you should convert it to UTC for database storage.

Comment: +1 for storing UTC timestamps. You also might want to check the phpBB source (or a similar PHP app), they have the user select their timezone upon registering, I think that is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for UTC timestamps, as they are easy to sort [alpha]numerically, rather than using complex date arithmetic.

Answer (score 54):

Using

```
setlocale  (LC_ALL,"0");
```

to get in the result the actual locale.

Comment: Thanks much!It was indeed in the PHP documentation, but somehow so much right in front of my nose that I had missed it :)

Comment: This should be the answer of the above question. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I can't get this to work so far on my machine (which is running PHP 5.4). Whatever local I set, "setlocale(LC_ALL,'0')" returns a single letter string with value "C" every single time!

Comment: I've got also this behaviour. But not always. Sometimes I get this string `LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF8;LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF8;LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF8;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C` and sometimes just `C`. Strange bug.

Comment: my setlocale(LC_ALL,"0") returns "C"... why?

Comment: @JohnSlegers, @Armin, @Tobia: `C` is the default setting, if no locale was ever set before. It means `nothing`. Try `money_format('%i', 123.45);` while you got this `C`. There will be no currency => `123.45`. But set it to `en_EN` and you will get `USD 123.45`. You can also set a local and after it set it back to the state before with following call `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C')`... See also here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
date_default_timezone_get; // Europe/London
```

or

```
if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}
```

Comment: Are those double single quotes there for a reason, or is it a typo?

Comment: can i use this to get locale date_default_timezone_get()