# How to Auto select User's country in registration form's select menu using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, location

How can get users country by default selected in my select box when he use my application from his location?

In javascript or php?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Download this database and extract the csv file
    https://sourceforge.net/projects/bowlfish/files/Others/ip2country/ip-to-country.csv.zip/download
    Create a mysql table "country_codes" at "DBname" database with 5 columns "ip_from" (bigint 20), "ip_to" (bigint 20), country_code2 (char 3), country_code3 (char 3), country_name (varchar 50) and import the csv file.

2)  create a file country.php with

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Establishing a database connection
$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","DBuser","DBpsw");
mysql_select_db("DBname");


// Query for getting visitor countrycode
$country_query  = "SELECT country_code2,country_name FROM country_codes ".
     "WHERE ip_from <= inet_aton('$ip') ".
      "AND ip_to >= inet_aton('$ip') ";


// Executing above query
$country_exec = mysql_query($country_query);


// Fetching the record set into an array
$ccode_array=mysql_fetch_array($country_exec);


// getting the country code from the array
$country_code=$ccode_array['country_code2'];


// getting the country name from the array
$country_name=$ccode_array['country_name'];


  // Display the Visitor coountry information
   //  echo "$country_code - $country_name";


// Closing the database connection
 mysql_close($dbh);


?>
```

3)  include_once 'country.php';  in you form file and use $country_name

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @reformed Cannot help on that. This is an old answer. There should be modern ways to accomplish that

Comment: If this answer depends upon that link, you should remove the answer then.