# Identify user's country with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to identify a user's country by using JavaScript. I want there are ways to do that using the IP address or geolocation. Is there any other way to accomplish this task? (let's say read it from user's computer) I want to avoid relying for example on an external service like this http://smart-ip.net/ because very often it takes quite a lot to respond. Any suggestion please?

Comment: You have to do this on the server.

Comment: [How to get visitor's location (i.e. country) using javascript geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation)

Comment: You can try checking this out: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/

Comment: Why are you trying to get the user's location?  Is it to direct them to the closest store?  To select the default language?  To ban users in certain countries?  IP to GeoLocation is mildly inaccurate at best, WILDLY inaccurate a lot of the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

or for more info

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions()
```

[image]

at this point maybe you are wondering how to get all the possible timezones

```
Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')
```

[image]