# remove parameter based on visitors country

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a javascript that allows me the function described,  I would like to get removed the parameter aff_id from any url depending on visitors country:

www.domain.com/join/?language=es&aff_id=3

resulting url: www.domain.com/join/?language=es

(can be this or any other url, what matters is that aff_id=X doesn´t show for that country in particular, but it does for others)

Is this possible? Could anyone show me something similar to what I´m looking for?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to lookup user IP-address in some geoip service (e.g. hostip.info). It can be done client-side. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation) questions to get some ideas on how this can be implemented.

Next you need to substitute a part of URL. That should be simple, e.g. using `location.replace`.