# Is there a script in Javascript That Can Determine What Country a User is In?

Tags: javascript

Would Javascript be good for this? Can JavaScript even do this? If Javascript is not good for this purpose, how about PHP?

Comment: you could issue an AJAX request to one of the IP geolocation services.

Comment: There is `navigator.language` which gives you the user's locale. You can't access user's IP address with JavaScript, if that's what you were thinking.

Comment: Does this question's answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation

Comment: @sabof language != country!

Comment: @epascarello I never said it was.

Comment: What about the [geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation)?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery version. conversion to standard Javascript is straightforward

```
$.get("http://ip-api.com/json", function(response) {
    console.log(response.country);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://ipinfo.io API for this.

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    console.log(response.country)
}, "jsonp");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Em6nU/