# How to find a users domain wheather the user is in canada or the usa and the redirect them to a file based on a specfic link they click, in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code im not the most experienced in javascript.

```
var x = document.domain;

function myFunction() {

    if(x == "usa"){
      window.location = "usafile"
    }
    elseif(x == "canada"){
      window.location = "canadafile"
    }
}
```

Comment: What if they're in Australia?

Comment: Just trying to find it for Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look their ip up in any ip to location service (hostip.info, maxmind). This will be accurate most of the time.

Check this answer: [How to get visitor's location (i.e. country) using javascript geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation)

Comment: Or use the http://ipinfo.io from that same answer. Just used this and works flawlessly.