# How to get location of website visitor without depending on JavaScript, since it will not work unless user allow it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website using ASP.NET MVC, how can I get the current location (Country, city, district, lat-lng geolocation) of each visitor browses my website depending on IP address?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and share your research. You're not the first person asking this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get visitor's location (i.e. country) using javascript geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get location by using IP address of visitor. Use web-service provided by ipinfodb.com :

```
            string url = string.Format("https://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key={0}&ip={1}&format=json", APIKey, ipAddress);
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string json = client.DownloadString(url);
                Location location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Location>(json);
                return location;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several services out there that can do this. Try, for example, this one: http://geoip.nekudo.com.
An example: http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/8.8.8.8
Look for "ip geolocation rest api".

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer has nothing to do with JavaScript!

Answer (score -1):

There are many geo-localization service you can use. For example, I do this way.

Put this tag inside your main .html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userIp"></script>
```

Than you will find a global variable called `userIp` with the calling ip address.
Than you can use any geolocation tool to get all the information you need.