# pure HTML/JS how to direct visitor to certain web page based on their location

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thanks for your time. Just like the title, what I need to accomplish is that

Whenever someone in the South Korea visit my site http://awebsite.com/ they will automatically goes to http://awebsite.com/kr/index.html instead of http://awebsite.com/index.html (so basically the "kr" folder)

If its from South  Korea, then they will be automatically point towards /kr/ folder instead.

How to achieve the above?

Thank you

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-geolocation

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp this can help you to get geolocation and then you can redirect.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use an IP detection API (for example, [ip-api.com](https://ip-api.com/), there are many similar services) to detect the location of the client, and when South Korea is detected as the location of the client, use `window.location.replace(...)` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage).