# Can I get country code from zoneId using java.time etc?

Tags: java, timezone, utc

Is there any country related info e.g. country code in the `java.time` methods e.g. `java.time.ZoneId`? I have a zone list retrieved via `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` and I am wondering if there is a possibility to get any country data e.g. country code from it?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with country code? The Locale? Or what exactly

Comment: Time zones are **time specific** and I don't think that it's possible to retrieve countries' profiles. Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-geolocation

Comment: @Lino Thanks for reply. I mean Alpha-2 codes on [this](https://www.iban.com/country-codes) page.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get the country code of a time zone.

Although the information is available in the `$JRE_HOME$\lib\tzmappings` file, there is no API making the information available to Java code. Also, the information seems to be incomplete in Java 11 and earlier.

You have to keep your own time zone "database" (just a flat file) for that information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What about using a 3rd party library e.g. **[timezonemap](https://github.com/dustin-johnson/timezonemap)** instead of keeping lots of values in db or *.yml file? I tested [timezonemap](https://github.com/dustin-johnson/timezonemap) and the only problem it may take too much time to search everywhere when I need US and Australia. When giving a region for min-max lat/long, it is fast. What would you suggest from these options? Or another opt?

Comment: @Rosa Sure, a third-party library is a good way to go.

Comment: Would you suggest any of them for Java and for JavaScript?

Comment: @Rosa [**Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).