# Is this possible to get default store country name using javascript in shopify?

Tags: javascript, themes, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

> I want to get default store country name using javascript code. i have setup 5 store in my shopify theme,i want to get default store name using javascript , is this possible ???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Shopify` global JS variable `Shopify.country`.

Comment: @Juandras Can you provide me code please

Comment: @Juandras please help me bro

Comment: @Juandras from this Country code is getting fetched but it is not of default country code .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-geolocation