# Get timezone off a mobile device?

Tags: php, timezone

I'm in the midst of programming a mobile site that should deal with different timezones. Is there a function that gets the timezone off the mobile device? I'm php Zend Framework based.

Comment: PHP scripts executes on server, not on device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get client's timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisely because the device is *mobile*, there is no point in determining the timezone on the server side. Instead, use [client-site time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the procedure for getting the timezone from a mobile device is the same as getting it from a desktop client. The mobile browser must support JavaScript or you have to ask for the user to choose and submit their timezone. See this question: [How to get client's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone)

Comment: Also see "Get client timezone (not GMT offset amount) in JS" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897478/get-client-timezone-not-gmt-offset-amount-in-js

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do this. You can estimate the user's time zone based on his IP address (geolocationing stuff), but that's not really accurate.

Just have a look at most forum scripts how they do it. In general they'll use a small JavaScript to compare server time(zone) and browser time(zone) - but there's no general API or HTTP header field for this.