# How can I get the timezone name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I know how to get the timezone offset, but what I need is the ability to detect something like "America/New York." Is that even possible from JavaScript or is that something I am going to have to guestimate based on the offset?

Comment: Here is a function Jon Nylander wrote, maybe it helps https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Comment: Here's a related answer that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19421672/1447034

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect timezone abbreviation using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954397/detect-timezone-abbreviation-using-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the client's time zone (and offset) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript)

Answer (score 494):

The [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions) supports getting the user timezone, and is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization) in all current browsers.

```js
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

Keep in mind that on some older browser versions that support the Internationalization API, the `timeZone` property is set to `undefined` rather than the user’s timezone string. As best as I can tell, at the time of writing (July 2017) [all current browsers except for IE11](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/#test-DateTimeFormat_resolvedOptions().timeZone_defaults_to_the_host_environment) will return the user timezone as a string.

Comment: Returns `undefined` in Firefox: `let timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;`

Comment: `let` anything will return `undefined`, you need to evaluate `timezone`, or only run `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Answer (score 61):

Most upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935836/5877243) is probably the best way to get the timezone, however, `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` returns IANA timezone name by definition, which is in English.

If you want the timezone's name in current user's language, you can parse it from `Date`'s string representation like so:

```js
function getTimezoneName() {
  const today = new Date();
  const short = today.toLocaleDateString(undefined);
  const full = today.toLocaleDateString(undefined, { timeZoneName: 'long' });

  // Trying to remove date from the string in a locale-agnostic way
  const shortIndex = full.indexOf(short);
  if (shortIndex >= 0) {
    const trimmed = full.substring(0, shortIndex) + full.substring(shortIndex + short.length);
    
    // by this time `trimmed` should be the timezone's name with some punctuation -
    // trim it from both sides
    return trimmed.replace(/^[\s,.\-:;]+|[\s,.\-:;]+$/g, '');

  } else {
    // in some magic case when short representation of date is not present in the long one, just return the long one as a fallback, since it should contain the timezone's name
    return full;
  }
}

console.log(getTimezoneName());
```

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Of course, this will not work as intended in some of the environments. For example, node.js returns a GMT offset (e.g. `GMT+07:00`) instead of a name. But I think it's still readable as a fallback.

P.S. Won't work in IE11, just as the `Intl...` solution.

Comment: This is a great solution. I am using the `timeZoneName: 'short'` to get the short form like EST, or GMT+0230 which I can use on the Java backend.

Answer (score 28):

A short possibility for a result in current user's language:

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {day:'2-digit',timeZoneName: 'long' }).substring(4));
```

Comment: I find this to be the most user-friendly example, since the user may not be located in the city returned by the other examples. For people looking for just the abbreviation like `PDT` or `EST` you can use this variation: 
 new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {day:'2-digit',timeZoneName: 'short' }).substring(4)

Answer (score 9):

If you're already using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) you can guess the timezone name:

```
moment.tz.guess(); // eg. "America/New York"
```

Comment: Please, mention that it is also simply possible without any dependencies:
`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Comment: Yep, although moment-js also guesses TZ for "browsers" that don't support that feature. :)

Comment: in IE11 `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` gives back `undefined`, but `moment.tz.guess()` returns correct value

Answer (score 4):

You can use this script. 
http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Fork or clone repository here.
https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Once you include the script, you can get the list of timezones in -  `jstz.olson.timezones` variable.

And following code is used to determine client browser's timezone.

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
tz.name();
```

Enjoy jstz!

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {day:'2-digit',timeZoneName: 'long' }).substring(4).match(/\b(\w)/g).join(''))
```

Comment: This is very brittle and breaks when the browser language isn't English.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write your own code by using the mapping table here:
http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

or, use moment-timezone library:
http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

See `zone.name; // America/Los_Angeles`

or, this library:
https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js

Comment: Not especially useful due to multiple timezones having the same offset

Answer (score -3):

To detect something like "America/New York.", you can use the `new LocalZone()` from the [Luxon library](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html).

```
import { LocalZone } from 'luxon';

const zoneName = new LocalZone().name;
```

Comment: This will not work in the browser but only in Node.js.

Answer (score -4):

This gets the timezone code (e.g., `GMT`) in older javascript (I'm using google app script with old engine):

```
function getTimezoneName() {
  return new Date().toString().get(/\((.+)\)/);
}
```

I'm just putting this here in case someone needs it.

Comment: I think that only works for `UTC`/`GMT`. It looks like others are spelled out; e.g., `Pacific Daylight Time`.

Answer (score -5):

In javascript , the Date.getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time-zone offset from UTC, in minutes, for the current locale.

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

Moment'timezone will be a useful tool.
http://momentjs.com/timezone/

**Convert Dates Between Timezones**

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: You didn't understand the que.

Comment: Your code samples aren't related to the original question. How would you use this library to return the name of the user's current time zone?