# Detect the ID of the current user timezone using moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

What I'm looking for is a way to detect the browser's timezone ID (as defined in the [Olson tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)) but I don't care for the exact ID, I just need the ID of a timezone that works the same as the user's one (for example "Europe/Rome" is fine if the user is in Paris).

I'm not interested in the current offset, I really need the timezone so that I can send it to the server to do computations for other dates (the server has the Olson tables too).

Theoretically, as I already use [Moment.js timezone library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) and have included the Olson tables, I don't need anything else, but I don't find any API to do the detection. I don't know if it's hidden somewhere or if somebody has it already written. One of the problems is that the current timezone plugin seems to keep its data private.

I **dont'** want a solution based on the integration of yet another copy or extract of the Olson tables (which I would have to maintain), I know there are a few libraries duplicating them, I want to use the ones I already have in Moment.js.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Comment: @MattJohnson This plugin contains an extract of the timezone data. That's what I specifically wanted to avoid.

Comment: It's not really an extract, those are well researched test points.  There are a lot of edge cases to consider.  I do understand your desire to stick with maintainable data, but I'm not sure that it is possible to take a direct approach.

Comment: Also, make sure you realize the [effects of ECMAScript 15.9.1.8](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/issue/68/effects-of-ecmascript-15918).  Moment.js is also affected by this [in many ways](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/831).

Comment: It's ES5 that is doing it wrong.  ES6 is better, but almost all browsers today are ES5.  See also [my blog post on this subject](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/)

Comment: I **had** misunderstood : I thought your citation was from an ES6 draft... I always supposed the browsers already implemented/used a correct calendar library as it's not exactly a totally new field.

Comment: One would think so, but apparently the designers of ECMAScript thought time zones were too complicated or something like that.  It's been in the spec since 1.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

moment now has the `guess()` API as [described here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/)

Comment: Oh good. I guess it's time to un-accept my own answer then :)

Answer (score 17):

I made a small script to do that detection. It starts by registering the ids of the available timezones, then, on a call to the `matches` function tests all timezone ids for the current time and the times 4 and 8 months later (to filter out the timezones with different daylight rules) and five years before.

Here it is :

```
<script src="moment-with-langs.min.js"></script>
<script src="moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="moment-timezone-data.js"></script>
<script>
var tzdetect = {
    names: moment.tz.names(),
    matches: function(base){
        var results = [], now = Date.now(), makekey = function(id){
            return [0, 4, 8, -5*12, 4-5*12, 8-5*12, 4-2*12, 8-2*12].map(function(months){
                var m = moment(now + months*30*24*60*60*1000);
                if (id) m.tz(id);
                return m.format("DDHHmm");
            }).join(' ');
        }, lockey = makekey(base);
        tzdetect.names.forEach(function(id){
            if (makekey(id)===lockey) results.push(id);
        });
        return results;
    }
};
</script>
```

If you just want one timezone id, simply use

```
var tzid = tzdetect.matches()[0];
```

[**Demonstration**](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/timezonedetect.html)

GitHub Repository : https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js

**Update :** The code here shown isn't compatible with the most recent versions of moment.js. Please refer to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js) for a maintained (free to use) code.

**2017 Update:** There's now an API in moment.js to guess the timezone. That's probably the best solution right now.

Comment: This is a great start, but it needs a way to provide tests for edge cases.  The tests you make now are reasonable, but don't cover everything.  It would make an excellent GitHub project, and moment plugin.  :)

Comment: I'll consider contributing to moment.js but as you know it (probably much better than me), I'll have to do more work on the topic before I do such a move. Your warnings here are very welcome and might be useful for other users.

Comment: @MattJohnson For now, I made [a github repository](https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js).

Comment: Cool.  If I get some time, I'll test it out and send a pull request with proposed changes.  May be a while before I can get to it.  Cheers!

Comment: Matching time format should include minutes, ie 'DDHHmm' so that times which differ by < 60 minutes are excluded.

Comment: @MartynDavis I merged your change.

Comment: @dystroy : how to get user pc timezone id ? it seems that this code tzdetect.matches()[0]; will not return user pc setting wise timezone id. please help if possible. thanks

Comment: @Thomas It should return a timezone which works the same than the user's timezone, which is enough as long as you don't need to display the name of the timezone.

Comment: the code seems it will return something like first element from array not user pc timezone.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me (in Cancún which is EST)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use the standard JavaScript API, you can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat.resolvedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions) where there is browser support:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; // "America/Los_Angeles"
```

`resolvedOptions` is currently (Jan 2016) available in all browsers except Safari on iOS and desktop: http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization

However, the `timeZone` property is currently [only available on Chrome](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/#test-DateTimeFormat_resolvedOptions().timeZone_defaults_to_the_host_environment).

Comment: Technically, that should be `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`, but either will work.  Except the current versions [have issues still](https://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/issues/detail?id=33).

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for this. I'm still unsure, though, and I don't know to what extend the specification can be considered mature today. I have no document describing it with enough detail. Do you have such a documentation ?

Comment: It's part of the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://norbertlindenberg.com/ecmascript/intl.html#sec-12.3.3), which is not yet finalized.  I agree that this is not mature enough to use today.

Comment: As poster says this works in Chrome and some other browsers, but support is patchy enough to make this risky e.g. this is NOT in Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score -1):

There's a javascript tool that does just that :

https://github.com/entraigas/jstz

It seems to deal with timezones ambiguity also.

Combined with momentJS timezone, you can get the timezone and show formatted date :

```
var tzObj = jstz.determine();
var timezoneCode = tzObj.name();
console.log(moment.tz(timeZoneCode).format());
```

Comment: Thanks for that but my requirement was precisely *"I dont' want a solution based on the integration of yet another copy or extract of the Olson tables"*.