# List of Timezones in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking for a list of time zones that corresponds to major cities. Like what [java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) can provide.
I mean, I want to resolve the `America/Los_Angeles` identifier to `UTC-8:00` in javascript.

Is there already an existing JSON file or format that has this feature?

I came across to [**this**](https://gist.github.com/ykessler/3349960) which is close to what I'm looking.

---

**UPDATE**

Solution: [Detect the ID of the current user timezone using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420582/detect-the-id-of-the-current-user-timezone-using-moment-js) *(Did not answer my question directly but solved my problem)*

Comment: Take database that fits your requirements and generate JSON from it.

Comment: I think this one does not need database since it is a fix or less chance to change in the future. I asked because I'm hoping that someone has already a known approach to it.

Comment: Any idea of doing the reverse. Given the offset, it returns the abbreviated form of the timezone.

Comment: You could convert the array in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54500197/217867) to JSON quite easily.

Answer (score 5):

I think, this will be benefit for you
http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: yup, I had also came across to this but I think this will not solve my question, It simply get the identifier of settled timezone identifier. Anyways, can you provide example of how to use it?

Comment: Lot's of sample code in the docs http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

Comment: @JonStødle thanks! [Zone Object](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/) is quite close but as I mention **It simply get the identifier of settled timezone identifier.**

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks for the leads.
[Detect the ID of the current user timezone using moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420582/detect-the-id-of-the-current-user-timezone-using-moment-js)