# How do I obtain the windows time zone string from Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list of timezones based of of .NET method [`System.TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones?view=netframework-4.8) provided from my MVC controller. What I would like to do is capture the user's timezone (client side)  and default the dropdown list to their timezone.

On both Chrome and Firefox when I type in `new Date()` to the console I can get a string like `Fri Jan 24 2020 08:50:02 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Other than parsing between the parentheses, is there a way to get the timezone string Eastern Standard Time?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246547/get-name-of-time-zone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get name of time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246547/get-name-of-time-zone)

Comment: @yW0K5o You should be able to flag the question as a duplicate if you find another question that answers the current one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the timezone name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772955/how-can-i-get-the-timezone-name-in-javascript)

Comment: The problem with Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone & moment.tz.guess(); is that I get "America/New_York" rather than "Eastern Standard Time" (And "America/New_York" isn't an option on the dropdown that's generated from GetSystemTimeZones)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this to get the gmt text. It is rought, but might work

```
new Date().toString().split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only gets me "America/New_York" rather than "Eastern Standard Time".

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current timezone offset in minutes from the dates `getTimezoneOffset` function. Then you can divide the number by `60` to get the actual offset in hours. Note that the offset is the additatively inverted number of the "GMT+0100" string.

```js
const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
console.log('Offset: ', offset);
console.log('UTC:    ', new Date().toUTCString());
console.log('GMT:    ', new Date().toString());
```

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset):

> The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time zone difference, in minutes, from current locale (host system settings) to UTC.

Comment: That would work great for the offset, but I'm actually looking for the string, i.e. "Eastern Standard Time". The dropdown menu I have has multiple options for each GMT time. (For example "Eastern Time Zone" and "Cuba Standard Time" have the same GMT time but are different options).

Comment: Can't you use the offset as the dropdown "values" and the full string as the "label"?

Comment: "Eastern Standard Time" is the actual value I need, my label is actually "(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)". The label could be changed if that would help but "Eastern Standard Time" is what I need to ultimately send to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to use `Moment`, which is a third party library for handling everything from time to dates. I really really recommend this.

Official Moment documentation: https://momentjs.com/

In your question you can get the time zone really easy using moment like:

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('z');  // PDT
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('z');  // PST

jun.tz('America/New_York').format('z');     // EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('z');     // EST

// This gets you your current timezone
moment().tz(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone).format('z')

// Other examples
jun.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST
dec.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST

jun.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 10pm EST
dec.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 11pm EST
```