# How can I get timezone name from date string in javascript in node environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a date in string format e.g. `2020-07-02T20:00:00.000+10:00`. It has a offset `+10:00` in the end. How can I get the timezone name from this string?

Below code will give me the offset in seconds which is `-600`. How can I get the timezone name in string? The value should be `'Australia/Melbourne'`.

```
> d=new Date('2020-07-02T20:00:00.000+10:00')
2020-07-02T10:00:00.000Z
> d.getTimezoneOffset()
-600
```

I'd like to use build-in function to achieve rather than 3rd part library.

Comment: Problem 1, there is more than one timezone name with that offest

Comment: No, it uses moment js which I don't want to use.

Comment: [The top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935836/4665) does not use moment at all

Comment: The top one returns a string like `Australian Eastern Standard Time` which is not what I want. I want to get the string `Australia/Melbourne` which can be used in `toLocaleDateString`.

Comment: Why should the function return Australia/Melbourne and not Australia/Hobart or Asia/Vladivostok? Or what if Australia decides to observe DST and +10 becomes +9 or +11?

Comment: Interesting , what browser? I get `Australia/Sydney` for my linked answer in FireFox, Chrome and Edge (All Win10)

Comment: All of them are ok as long as it represents +10:00 offset.

Comment: @JonP not in browser, it is in node.js environment.

Comment: Fair enough, I've voted to re-open. I might suggest editing your question to highlight the fact this is for node (some times tags get glossed over)