# What's the correct format of the default javascript Date returned object

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

When the new Date() is called, it returns something like this

```
Wed Jul 13 2022 16:15:35 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

So I was curious what is the correct format used in that case? I tried building it with the following format: **E MMM d yyyy H:mm:ss zzzz** However the result was

```
Wed Jul 13 2022 16:15:00 GMT-06:00
```

This is the closest I can get. I've been searching the internet but can't find the correct format. By the way, the local used is en_US

Example:

```
let momentDate = moment(date, 'E MMM d yyyy H:mm:ss zzzz', true);
```

If I execute the momentDate.isValid() it returns false.

Comment: What you're seeing comes from date's toString method, who's behavior is described in detail [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what formatting tool you're using to build a date string like that. The answer to your question will depend on what tool you're using. Could you edit with more information?

Comment: (e.g. what function are you calling that takes `E MMM d yyyy H:mm:ss zzzz` as an argument and spits back out a formatted string? What library is this from?)

Comment: `new Date()` returns an object, not a string. It doesn't have a format. In many cases, when a *Date* instance is converted to string then [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is used (but other formats might be used too, e.g. the SO console seems to use *toISOString*). It produces a single format per ECMA-262, it doesn't take any parameters so any you supply are ignored.

Comment: I'm using moment.js

Comment: Example:

let momentDate = moment(date, 'E MMM d yyyy H:mm:ss zzzz', true);
if I execute the momentDate.isValid() it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString#description): `Date.prototype.toString()` returns a string representation of the Date in the format specified in [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/).

That last part is described as:

- Optionally, a timezone name consisting of:

  - space
  - Left bracket, i.e. "("
  - An implementation dependent string representation of the timezone, which might be an abbreviation or full name (there is no standard for names or abbreviations of timezones), e.g. "Line Islands Time" or "LINT"
  - Right bracket, i.e. ")"

Different date formatting libraries in different frameworks will have different ways to get a string representation of the time zone and, importantly, this is implementation-specific. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68065499/120955) shows one way to get that value, basically by outputting it from a date and parsing the result. But you should not rely on it (or really any aspect of date outputs, apart from `toISOString()`) having any consistency between browsers or other execution environments.

> Until ECMAScript 2018 (edition 9), the format of the string returned by Date.prototype.toString was implementation dependent. Therefore it should not be relied upon to be in the specified format.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString#description

> output variations are by design, and allowed by the specification... you cannot expect to be able to compare the results of toLocaleString() to a static value
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#avoid_comparing_formatted_date_values_to_static_values