# toTimeString inconsistent time zone name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date, datetime

I'm noticing the following weird behaviour for the `toTimeString` method.

```
const date1 = new Date("2022-09-23T00:00:00.00Z")
const date2 = new Date()


date1.toTimeString() 
//17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Saving Time)

date2.toTimeString()
// 15:06:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

I've also noticed that result for `date1` even depends on the device region settings (for Mac at least)

```
date1.toTimeString() 

// if region is set to Canada
// 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Saving Time)

// if region is set to United States
// 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Another observation

```
date2.toTimeString()
// this is the result for both United States and Canada
// 15:06:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

A couple of questions

1. Why does the result depend on how the date is constructed?
   (`new Date("2022-09-23T00:00:00.00Z")` vs `new Date`)
2. For `new Date("2022-09-23T00:00:00.00Z")`, why does the result depend on the device setting?
3. The result seems consistent when no arguments are passed e.g `new Date()`. Can we assume that this will produce a consistent timezone name regardless of device settings?

Note: I also noticed a same behaviour with `date-fns-tz`

EDIT: added one more example above.

Another question:
4.In contrary to question 2, `new Date().toTimeString()` is not influenced by region setting. Why is that the case

EDIT 2: I figured it out.
For countries with day light savings. The behaviour of `toTimeString()` will produce different timezone based on when the timestamp falls in.

Leaving this thread here since it might be helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why does the result depend on how the date is constructed? (new Date("2022-09-23T00:00:00.00Z") vs new Date)

The timestamp "2022-09-23T00:00:00.00Z" is parsed with zero offset due to the trailing "Z". That effectively makes it UTC.

Calling `new Date()` creates a *Date* instance for the current date and time. *toTimeString* returns the time that a *Date* instance represents based on system settings. So for a given instance, if you change the location in system settings to a place with a different offset, you'll get a different time.

If regional settings are for a place that observes daylight saving time (DST), then you'll also get a different offset (and civil timezone name) for dates at times of the year when DST is and isn't in effect.

> 2. For new Date("2022-09-23T00:00:00.00Z"), why does the result depend on the device setting?

The *Date* instance created is exactly the same regardless of system settings because the offset is fixed as 0 in the timestamp. The result of [*toTimeString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.totimestring) depends on system settings because that's were it gets its information for the host offset and civil timezone name from.

> 3. The result seems consistent when no arguments are passed e.g new Date(). Can we assume that this will produce a consistent timezone name regardless of device settings?

No. Timezone names are not standardised and are implementation dependent [per ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-timezoneestring). However, the actual offset should be consistent.

I suggest reading [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) for some background.

Answer (score 2):

1. First case you call the Date constructor with string representation of the date `2022-09-23` with the time `00:00:00 (GMT offset 0)` and it returns the Date object instance for the 09/23/2022 00:00:00. Second case you call empty Date constructor which returns the Date object instance with current date and time.
2. Next, when you call the `toTimeString()` method it returns the time portion of a Date object interpreted in the local timezone (see more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString).
3. If you would like to get the local time zone name better see here [How can I get the timezone name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772955/how-can-i-get-the-timezone-name-in-javascript)

Comment: Since `toTimeString` interprets in local timezone, then shouldn't it be consistent regardless of how the date is constructed? aka why is one `GMT-0700` but the other is `GMT-0800`

Comment: @tpszhao—DST in the US in 2022 was from 13 Mar to 6 Nov. One date is for 22 Sep (PDT) when daylight saving is being observed and the other is for 19 Nov (PST) when it isn't.