# Handling Time Zone Conversions with Firestore Timestamps in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm working on a Firebase Cloud Function that queries Firestore data based on date ranges provided in the request payload. However, I've encountered challenges with time zone conversions impacting the accuracy of the queried data. Specifically, Firestore stores timestamps in UTC, and I need to compare them with dates sent in the request payload, which might be in different time zones.

I've tried converting the incoming dates to Firestore Timestamps and using them in queries, but inconsistencies persist, especially with time zone differences.

What's the best approach to handle time zone conversions accurately within Cloud Functions when querying Firestore using Firestore Timestamps compared to dates sent in the request payload? How can I ensure the queried date range aligns correctly despite varying time zones?

Any insights, best practices, or alternative methodologies to handle this time zone conversion challenge in Firestore Timestamp-based queries within Cloud Functions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help!

The following is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.getExpenses = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  if (!context.auth.uid) {
    return {
      error: 'Unauthorized'
    };
  }

  const requesterStartDateTime = new Date(data.startDate);
  const requesterEndDateTime = new Date(data.endDate);

  // Set the time boundaries for the start date to the beginning of the day
  requesterStartDateTime.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  // Set the time boundaries for the end date to the end of the day
  requesterEndDateTime.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

  const shopId = data.shopId;
  try {
    const expensesSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('expensesRegister')
      .where('shopId', '==', shopId)
      .get();

    const expenses = [];

    for (const doc of expensesSnapshot.docs) {
      const expenseName = doc.data().expenseName;
      const expenseDocReference = doc.ref; // Reference to the expensesRegister document
      const businessExpensesRef = expenseDocReference.collection('business_expenses');
      const businessExpensesSnapshot = await businessExpensesRef
        .where('date', '>=', requesterStartDateTime)
        .where('date', '<=', requesterEndDateTime)
        .get();
      let totalAmount = 0;

      businessExpensesSnapshot.forEach(expenseDoc => {
        totalAmount += expenseDoc.data().amount;
      });

      expenses.push({
        expenseName,
        totalAmount,
        expenseDocumentReference: '/expensesRegister/' + expenseDocReference.id, // Include the reference here
      });
    }

    return expenses; // Returning the array directly without a key

  } catch (error) {
    return {
      error: error.message
    };
  }
});
```

my payload is in this format

```
{
  "data": {    
    "startDate": "2023-12-4",    
    "endDate": "2023-12-04 23:59:59.999",    
    "shopId": "60322786"    
  }    
}
```

Comment: You should first ensure that you are sending dates to your backend using an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant format (this would be `someDate.toISOString()` in JavaScript), or a standard numeric-like Unix time (this would be `someDate.getTime()` in JavaScript which is in milliseconds or `Timestamp.now().toJSON()` using a Firestore Timestamp which is in nanoseconds). Ideally your start and end timestamps should be computed on the client as it will have the needed timezone information.

Comment: Alternatively, send the [IANA Timezone Location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935836) with those dates (`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` in JavaScript) and then [parse on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030) as appropriate either manually or using a library.