# My posted date via php is off 1 hour... How to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, date, post

My date is ahead 1 hour when I post to mySQL via php.  I'm in Los Angeles.  How can i make the time correct?

Here is what I currently have:

```
$date = date("m/d/y g:i A") ;
```

Comment: `I'm in Los Angeles` - that's your problem right there! (Just kidding. It's likely a time zone issue. Where is your server located?)

Comment: Good question.  In Colorado, which is central time zone...  there one hour ahead

Comment: Is it possible to get the time from the users computer?

Comment: not easily, no. Here's a good answer to that: [How do I show datetime in the same time zone as user using PHP or javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2934465)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get the time zone PHP is using `date_default_timezone_get();`

If you're in Los Angeles you can set your time zone temporarily for only the current script
`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Also pass `T` in the date function:

`echo date("D M j G:i:s T Y");` outputs `Mon May 25 16:23:49 EDT 2009`

Answer (score 0):

see

[`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

like

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if servers time is correct ( on linux use date shell command). If yes, you just set the time and you're good.

If not you have to change it in php with [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) or [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your specific case, but I had saved the date as UTC / GMT time, so I had to use the gmdate function instead of date. E.g.

`gmdate("H:i",$time)`