# How to set TimeZoneInfo in ASP.NET data bound DropDownList to user's time zone?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, timezone

I have a web app hosted with GoDaddy (so the web server is in Arizona - Mountain Time).  My users are mostly in Central Time Zone, but I could have some from other time zones.

I have a web page with a databound dropDownList using TimeZoneInfo, and I want to set the selected value of this dropDownList to whatever timeZone the user is in.  Here's my code currently:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownListTimeZone.DataSource = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
    DropDownListTimeZone.DataBind();

    TimeZoneInfo cst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
    DropDownListTimeZone.SelectedValue = cst.DisplayName;
}
```

It's ok, but I want it to be smarter for those users who aren't in CST.  I was hoping there is some way to grab the user's TimeZoneInfo from something like Page.Request.?? but I can't figure it out.

Is there an easy solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would require a bit of javascript; since it's running on the user's browser, it could pick up whatever time zone the computer is set to and set the selected item in the dropdown accordingly.

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping there is some way to grab the user's TimeZoneInfo from something like Page.Request

There is not. You can guess from the client side using JavaScript—see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853474/can-i-get-the-browser-time-zone-in-asp-net-or-do-i-have-to-rely-on-js-operations)—but it is just a guess.

There's no interface to get definitive client timezone information from a browser. So you'll definitely want to provide the user-selected setting, using the JS guess as a default value.