# Denerate date time by passing time zone in javascript

Tags: javascript

My requirement is to get the date and time by passing the timezone using the javascript.

Is there any javascript function by which i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

it can get pretty complicated but there is a good js library you can use
https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home

Comment: also you can reference this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853474/can-i-get-the-browser-time-zone-in-asp-net-or-do-i-have-to-rely-on-js-operations