# ToLocalTime shows wrong time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am running a website in IIS on my local PC, I save a date as UTC and call .ToLocalTime() on it in the front end mvc website. If I run the website on my local PC it outputs the correct date and time adjusted for DST. If I run it in Azure in region UK West I get 1 hour behind. This hasn't been an issue until today i.e. the clocks changed on Saturday. Do I need to raise a ticket with Azure? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If it is helpful, please mark it as answer that will help more communities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure App server is using  UTC time. If your site is not global just for UK. We can use the following code to get the UK local time.

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"); //UK time zone
DateTimeOffset  time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, tz);
lab_time.Text = time.DateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //display the datetime with label.
```

If your website is to be global that you may need to use javascrpt to do that, more detail please refer to another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853474/can-i-get-the-browser-time-zone-in-asp-net-or-do-i-have-to-rely-on-js-operations).

Comment: Yes, site is UK only, is there anyway I can set it globally for the entire application?

Comment: As I mentioned that we need to use javascript to do that. Based on my experience, we can't get the globally local timezone from the server backend.

Answer (score 0):

**Time-zone depends on the the server location** literally.

I had faced the same issue. I had my server in Singapore and it used to clash with my zone, India.

**It would affect the time and date formats too.**

So, `Better not use` the `ToLocalTime()` `at the server` side. just `get the UTC time from the server` and `convert to` whatever `local time at the client` side. Issue resolved!

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, but my server is in the UK, so should be no problem?

Comment: But when the time changes, I have no idea what they do at Azure. And, if your website is to be global, it would be a problem!

Comment: Actually I am not sure this is true. My UK Azure instance runs in utc and my qa and production servers (both in UK) run in GMT so server location isn't the issue