# How to Show Local Time Zone in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to show Local Time Zone for each user login from there system by using following code:

```
localStorage.localTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName;
```

Its Working proper for me on my local. I checked many times by changing **time zone** on my **local project**.But, after code publish on server it only showing **UTC** Time Zone for each user while others have **IST** and **PST** Time Zone. Because, My server has set to **UTC** Time Zone.
Can someone help me to short out this problem on server without changing time zone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get the browser time zone in ASP.NET or do I have to rely on JS operations to retrieve the information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853474/can-i-get-the-browser-time-zone-in-asp-net-or-do-i-have-to-rely-on-js-operations)

Answer (score 0):

To understand the issue, you'll need to think about **where** the code is executed.

1. User requests login page from the browser
2. User enters credentials
3. Request is made to your server
4. The `localStorage.localTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName;` code is executed on the server
5. The server creates a response containing the time

Your only choice is to get the timezone from the browser [How can I get the timezone name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772955/how-can-i-get-the-timezone-name-in-javascript)
and send it to your backend.